# How to identify a string as a binaryoperator

Tags: python

Perhaps this is an easy question, but I'm new to Python and haven't seen anyone else post anything similar to this.

We have a list:

```
lst1 = ["5", "+", "1"]
```

or

```
lst2 = ["10", "/", "2"]
```

How can one interpret this to: 5 + 1 or 10/2 ? I understand that you can write: int(lst2[0]) and then you would get 10, but how do you do the same with "+" or "/"?

Comment: Do you want to implement a simple calculator in Python?

Comment: No, not really. Just wondering how you transform "+" to be the binaryoperator +. That is removing the string. @voldmar

Comment: This is a bit broad, as the question is basically "What is a parser, and how do I write one?" For example, you *could* write `int(lst2[0])`, but how do you know that the string is a valid argument for `int`, or that `int` is the right function to call?

Comment: I don't think this is broad at all. Simply wondering how you can take "/" and make it to /. @chepner

Comment: @Agentsmith2.0 For this very constrained toy example, see any of the provided answers. You don't simply convert an input string into a Python operator literal, though; you need to map it to an appropriate function first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you "know" that your list has three strings, with the first and last representing integers and the middle one representing one of a fixed set of operators, you just need a mapping from the operator to a function that implements it. For example:

```
import operator

ops = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, "/": operator.div}
lst1 = ["5", "+", "1"]
f = ops[lst1[1]]
operand1 = int(lst1[0])
operand2 = int(lst1[2])
result = f(operand1, operand2)
```

However, things get complicated once you start allowing more general inputs, as you need some logic for deciding what parts of the list represent what. For that, you need:

1. A *grammar*, which identifies what role each element of your list plays
2. A *parser*, which uses the grammar to convert each string to a usuable value
3. An *interpreter*, which evaluates the thing produced by the parser to produce
    a final value.

There may also be a *tokenizer*, which is what would convert a single string input like `"5 + 1"` into a list of tokens that the parser uses for its input.

Any further general discussion about how to define any of the 4 concepts defined above is far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: operator.div didn't work for me, so I went with operator.truediv instead.

Comment: Whether `/` corresponds to `div` or `truediv` in Python 2 depends on whether or not `from __future__ import division` was used. In Python 3, there is no `operator.div`; `truediv` always corresponds to `/` and `floordiv` corresponds to `//`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, here is a snippet you may start with:

```
import operator
operators = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '/': operator.truediv, '*': operator.mul}

first, op, second = lst
first, op, second = int(first), operators[op], int(second)
op(first, second)
```

`operator` module contains operators as a functions, so you can map symbols to the operators. Note that I’ve used `truediv` for `/`, you may want to use variant which return int always

Answer (score 1):

You can't transform the string `"+"` to the operator `+` because operators are not things that *exist* at runtime. Operators only exist in code. You *can* map the string `"+"` to a function that takes two arguments and returns their sum, though. Functional equivalents for most operators exist in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module:

```
lst1 = ["5", "+", "1"]

import operator

op_table = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv
}

lhs = int(lst1[0])
op = op_table[lst1[1]]
rhs = int(lst1[2])

print('result:', op(lhs, rhs))  # output: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard function eval()
https://www.journaldev.com/22504/python-eval-function

```
lst1 = ["5", "+", "1"]
result1 = eval("".join(lst1))  # 6

lst2 = ["10", "/", "2"]
result2 = eval("".join(lst2))  # 5.0
```